# Limit JOIN to one result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query that make me crazy...

I have a table establishment with columns id, latitude, longitude.
Another table event with columns id, establishment_id, date.

I would like to get a single event for each establishment, and more precisely the closest one in time. For now I have :

```
SELECT et.latitude, et.longitude, ev.*
FROM establishment et
    JOIN event ev ON et.id = ev.establishment_id
WHERE ev.date_event >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY ev.date_event ASC
```

But this is giving me the full list of events ordered perfectly. I need to get only one event for each establishment_id thought...

Do you have any idea if it is possible?

Comment: It's possible. You need to replace EVENT with a subquery that returns only 1 row per per establishment WHERE that row is considered the closest

Comment: If two ev.date_event are equal, which event would you want? Or will this not occur?

Comment: GROUP BY is ok but doesn't show me the 3 closest for each establishment it takes the 3 firsts encountered events for each establishment.

Comment: @MarcusAdams - I can't have two similar dates I check it before inserting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you do it with a `JOIN` (can also be done with a subquery, however, generally this method outperforms the subquery method):

```
SELECT et.latitude, et.longitude, ev.*
FROM establishment et
  JOIN event ev1
  ON ev1.establishment_id = et.id
  AND ev1.date_event >= CURDATE()
  LEFT JOIN event ev2
  ON ev2.establishment_id = et.id
  AND ev2.date_event >= CURDATE()
  AND ev2.date_event < ev1.date_event
WHERE ev2.establishment_id IS NULL
```

It first does the proper join for events >= current date, then does another left join to see if there is another event with the same establishment_id that's before the first, and filters it out if there is.

Comment: @jmail, the first join should have been inner join. I fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `MAX(ev.date_event)` gives you the the event closest in time, this should be able to do the job.

BTW, you didn't mention that you need events from current date only, if this isn't a requirement then `WHERE` clause should be removed.

(not executed so look out for syntax)

```
SELECT et.latitude, et.longitude, ev.establishment_id, MAX(ev.date_event)
FROM establishment et
    JOIN event ev ON et.id = ev.establishment_id
WHERE ev.date_event >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY et.latitude, et.longitude, ev.establishment_id
```